# Problems with R in eclipse for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writting a class in eclipse for android and i am having problems with my R.layout.main.

```
public class createplayer extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createplayer);//problems with R

    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of the Android SDK are you using? I get this problem with all versions, but it appears to happen less with more recent versions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Like user717572 said. Try cleaning your project, sometimes things get messed up
2. Check your imports; remove `import android.R`, the problem is that Eclipse is looking for Android.R.layout.main instead of com.your.package.R.layout.main. So another alternative to is to replace `import android.R` with `import com.your.package.R` if removing it doesn't solve your problems.
3. And then of course make sure you have a layout called `createplayer`

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports for `import android.R` and remove it. And otherwise try 
project->clean.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of problems are you having?

Cleaning your project may do the trick.

Otherwise, if R is not being created, there is probably an aapt error in parsing your xml files.
You can manually run:

```
aapt package -m -v -J <path to your gen folder>/gen -M <path to your manifest>/AndroidManifest.xml -S <path to your res folder>/res -I <path to your android-sdk>/platforms/android-5/android.jar
```

This will list out where the problems are if your IDE is not telling you.

Comment: from the command line... if you're using eclipse, you should see the exact command you need scroll by in the console. You can copy that into a dos/linux command prompt/terminal to run it.